# Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

Following Michael Hartl's ROR tutorial getting this weird error after following the instructions in section 3.2 Tests. 
I run the command:  bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
I get the error:

bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': no such file to load -- /Users/name/Desktop/ROR/sample-app/spec/requests/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`load_spec_files'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in`run'
    from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that it's looking for the file in /Users/name/Desktop/ROR/sample-app/**spec/requests/spec/requests/**static_pages_spec.rb

Are you already in the spec/requests/ directory when trying to run this command?  The assumption is that you're in the project's home directory; if you're already in spec/requests/, you can just run:

bundle exec rspec static_pages_spec.rb